# collectionView numberOfItemsInSection coming up 0

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview

my collectionView numberOfItemsInSection keeps coming up 0 with following code:

```
return friendProfPics.count; //GET NOTHING

NSLog(@"Friend Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[friendProfPics count]); //GET NOTHING
```

However, up in my ViewDidLoad, I am correctly populating the Array and get my counts and data:

```
friendProfPics = [[result objectForKey:@"data"] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"Result from Facebook: %@", result); // GET DATA
NSLog(@"Array of Facebook friends Using App: %@", friendProfPics); //GET DATA
NSLog(@"Friend Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[friendProfPics count]); //GET COUNT
```

Why doesn't the data seem to carry down into collectionView number of items in section? I'm sure i'm missing something stupid but i have tried everyday from Sunday its not working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you have to create a strong property of friendProfPics (actually, this is not a right nomination according iOS dev rules...)?

Comment: thank you. I've tried a strong property of friendProPics too but does not work. I'm not sure what your comment in parenthesis means.

Comment: Could you also share the implementation of `-numberOfItemsInSection:` and the declaration of `friendProfPics`? Breakpoints in `viewDidLoad` and the delegate method would help to track the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint at the `friendProfPics =...` line and one at the `return friendProfPics.count` line. Which one is called first?

My guess is that the later is called first. If so, then the solution is to call `reloadData` on the table view immediately after the `friendProfPics = ...` line. Make sure that line isn't being called while in a background thread though.